# Unusual javascript Regex result, explanation please!

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm developing in VS2005 and have some JS code in my page. I have set a breakpoint during a particular loop where I was having an issue. Here is my little conversation with the IDE--

```
? ind
/d/g
? ind.test("d")
true
? ind.test("dtn")
false
? ind.test("dtn")
true
? ind.test("dtn")
false
? ind.test("dtn")
true
? ind.test("dtn")
false
```

Why is the test alternating between true and false? `ind` is my RegEx - I set it like this:

```
case "datetime" : ind = new RegExp("d","g");break;
```

## UPDATE

So I've solved my issue by changing my declaration to

```
ind = /d/;
```

ie omitting the global modifier. I suppose that

```
ind = RegExp("d");
```

would work equally as well.

The question remains though. Why was the global modifier causing the `test` to alternate between true and false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As with exec (or in combination with
>   it), test called multiple times on the
>   same global regular expression
>   instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

So what exactly happens here is that since you're using the global option for the regex, it will continue to search the string after it found an match.

```
ind.test("d")
```

This will find d at **position 0**.

```
ind.test("d")
```

This will now search for d starting at **position 1**, but since that's the end of the string it will not find anything therefore returning **false**.

We can use the `lastIndex` property of the regex to proof that:

```
ind.lastIndex
>> 0
ind.test("d")
>> true
ind.lastIndex
>> 1
ind.test("d")
>> false
```

Comment: +1 I was just writing this when I noticed that somebody else had already answered :)

Answer (score 3):

Calling `re.test(str)` is equivalent to `re.exec(str) != null` (see [specification of `RegExp.prototype.test(string)`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.10.6.3)).

And when calling [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) on a regular expression with *g* modifier repeatedly, the search is not started at the begin of the string but at the position of where the previous search ended (`lastIndex`, initialized with `0`):

> If your regular expression uses the "`g`" flag, you can use the `exec` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).

That’s why you’re getting this odd result.