# difference between 'var a = 2' and 'this.a = 2'

Tags: javascript, closures

I just discovered the weirdest bug in some javascript code dealing with `RegExp.test`. I had a regular expression `regexp` declared inside a function and I had a closure that had a reference to `regexp` and I was using the closure to iterate over an array of strings to test them with the help of `collect` from prototype.js, i.e.

```
function some_func() {
  var regexp = /regular_expression/;
  an_array_of_strings.collect(
     function(str) {
       if (regexp.test(str)) {
         do_something();
       }
     }
  );
}
```

The really weird thing was that calling `regexp.test(str)` inside the closure would alternate between `true` and `false` on the same input. I looked at the source for `RegExp.test` and I didn't see anything fishy but there was something going on because how can the same string pass and fail the same regular expression. After staring some more at `RegExp.test` I basically concluded that variables declared in `RegExp.test` were continuing to exist between invocations and were messing up subsequent invocations. So here's the question: What is the difference between

```
this.a = 2;
```

and

```
var a = 2;
```

when the above statements appear inside a method being called on an object inside a closure that holds a reference to that object? I'm asking because the bug disappears when I move `regexp.test` outside the closure. When `regexp.test` is called outside the closure then it doesn't flip-flop between `true` and `false` on each call. I have no idea why this is happening.

**Edit**: When I was moving the `regexp` outside the closure I was forgetting to add the global option so that's why the bug was disappearing. Thanks [Ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't show your RegExp but I just answered something similar to this, I suppose that you're using the `global` option in your RegExp, which has some interesting side effects.

> As with exec (or in combination with
>   it), test called multiple times on the
>   same global regular expression
>   instance will advance past the
>   previous match.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

So what exactly happens here is that since you're using the global option for the regex, it will continue to search the string after it found an match.

```
regexp.test("d")
```

This will find d at **position 0**.

```
regexp.test("d")
```

This will now search for d starting at **position 1**, but since that's the end of the string it will not find anything therefore returning **false**.

We can use the `lastIndex` property of the regex to proof that:

```
regexp.lastIndex
>> 0
regexp.test("d")
>> true
regexp.lastIndex
>> 1
regexp.test("d")
>> false
```

So to solve the issue you need to remove the `global` option from your RegExp.

**Disclaimer, this is a copy of my previous answer:**
[Unusual javascript Regex result, explanation please!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202947/unusual-javascript-regex-result-explanation-please/4203173#4203173)

Comment: What’s the point of this answer? What does this have to do with `var` and `this`?

Comment: There's not `var` and `this` in his question, he's speculating about internals of `RegExp.test` which I'm sure there's no `this.a` inside it, since it's native C code.

Comment: Oh man how the hell did I miss that. You're right. This is exactly what's happening. The problem is not because of the closure it is because of the global option.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question, as at first glance they appear to be identical.

I would surmise that `this.a` is owned by the function, but may also extend for the life of that function, not just the function call itself; whereas `var a` would be created and destroyed each time the function is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) about the wonders of `this` in JS. The meaning of `this` changes quite dramatically, depending on how you use your functions.

Comment: Ah but it shouldn't be difficult at all when the function is called as a method. When called as a method like in `regexp.test(str)` there should be no ambiguity about `this` because it refers to `regexp`

Comment: I would guess that both your function do_something() and your closure are owned by the window. You might include some silly debug code similar to console.debug(this) or console.debug(this.getAttribute('id')). It could at least provide clues as to what this is, as far as your js execution is concerned.